# How to parameterise a value in Soap request

Tags: soapui

I am new to soapUI so getting to grips with the tool, so any help would be much appreciated..

We have two environment configured (DEV, Staging) each with different end points which enables me to run my testsuite on either of the two environment.

As part of request in one of my testcases, I need to supply an 'accountID' however this accountID is different for each Environment therefore I would like to know how and where I can add the logic that would enable me to chose different account ID depending on the envionment I am selecting at the project level?

Please see attached image of the accountID filed that I am currently having to manually change depending on which server I am running the test on...

If solution is groovy script based , then could you please provide what the script should look like because my scripting skill at this point isn't that great..

Cheers

Shan[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom property to project. You can redefine value of this property in different environments. In test case you can access this property as ${#Project#property_name}

Comment: Ok as per you instruction,I selected the project and then added a property called 'accountID' with no default values under the 'Custom properties' tab. Then went to 'Environments' tab and selected the 'DEV' environment which I had previously added, followed by selecting the 'Custom Properties' tab and against the ‘accountId’ I set the value to '12345'. 

Following that I went to the test step that requires this account ID I types this in ${#Project#accounID} …
unfortunately upon running the test, I got..
faultcode:a:DeserializationFailed

Please could you kindly highlight where I went wrong?

Comment: I've added two further screen shot to help you understand what I've done.

Comment: Above solution worked, not sure why it didn't work the first time round - thanks Artem for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

At times there can be test case specific properties, similarly property for specific applicable and may be really applicable/make sense to define at project level.

So the same properties can be accessed in the *test request steps* as below similar to project property

- Test Case Level property - *${#TestCase#TEST_CASE_PROPERTY_NAME}*
- Test Suite Level property - *${#TestSuite#TEST_SUITE_PROPERTY_NAME}*
- Project Level property - *${#Project#PROJECT_PROPERTY_NAME}*

In case, the same properties needs to be access in *groovy scripts* in below way:

```
def propValueTC = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue('TEST_CASE_PROPERTY_NAME') 
def propValueTS = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('TEST_SUITE_PROPERTY_NAME') 
def propValueP = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue('PROJECT_PROPERTY_NAME') 
//or
def propValueTC = context.expand('${#TestCase#TEST_CASE_PROPERTY_NAME}')
def propValueTS = context.expand('${#TestSuite#TEST_SUITE_PROPERTY_NAME}')
def propValueP = context.expand('${#Project#PROJECT_PROPERTY_NAME}')
```

Similarly one can use setPropertyValue('property','value') as counter part to get