# How to extract token from response and pass it to next api-requests in SOAPUI

Tags: api, testing, soap, soapui

I try testing web-service with SOAPUI. I face with problem that i don`t know how to pass access token from the first response to second request. I have 8 requests and want to run them together.But but after my first request(Remote Login) I get the access token for user and i need using it in next requests. I have to do it manually. Could you help me, how i can get token from the first request and pass it to next requests automatically.In this case, all the case must be started by pressing 1 button.

Comment: Please edit your question to show some code you already have

Comment: Agreed. Helping you will be much easier, when we can see your testcase, names of teststeps etc...

Comment: @Steen, I only have a WSDL URL through which I get a list of requests(web-services). One of them "RemoteLogin" in the answer of which comes the token to access the user which I use in the following queries. I need pass this token to others steps automatically. Can i do this with Groovy script? And do I need a PRO version SOAPUI for that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. No, you don't need the PRO version. And it still won't make much sense to show a groovy script example, where I put best-guesses in teststep name, path to the entity you want to transfer etc... If you show the response of the RemoveLogin request, it will be trivial to create a groovy script that will return a value, which then can be inserted into the request of the next webservice call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open request editor in SoapUI , it allows you to take parameter from earlier response (right click on request parameter and then select data and choose your value).
I am not sure whether this is available only in SoapUI Pro. However even if that is case , you need to do below-
1.fire your first request
2.get rseponse value of access token. store it as test case property
3.use test case property while creating next request .

refer-
[Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715491/how-to-parameterise-a-value-in-soap-request)